# I have 4 GB RAM in both of the available slots; can I upgrade one of them to 8 GB?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, memory

Does having unequal size RAM affect performance? 
I want to make this upgrade because I run out of RAM while playing games and doing other resource-intensive stuff. My PC is a Dell 7577. 
Will it run in single channel or dual channel after the upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the upgrade it may run in single channel, fully or partly.

For full dual channel, both RAM sticks must be totally identical in all respects.
Otherwise, with 4GB+8GB, and if your motherboard supports it, you will be
running in
[Flex Mode](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005657/boards-and-kits.html),
where only the lower 4GB of both sticks run in dual channel mode.

However, dual channel is unlikely to have any impact on the performance,
so isn't an important consideration here.

Comment: To add on that last line, the difference between running Single Channel and Dual Channel is barely a 1% difference, based on a series of testing between different RAM configurations running different games: https://techguided.com/single-channel-vs-dual-channel-vs-quad-channel/

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

See the [specs](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/nl/nl/nlbsdt1/inspiron-15-7577-laptop/inspiron-15-7577-setupandspecs/geheugen):

> Per slot: 4 GB, 8 GB, 16 GB
>
> Total memory: 4 GB, 8 GB, 12 GB, 16 GB en 32 GB

You can only get to 12GB with one 4GB and one 8GB module. But they don't say 20GB or 24GB.

Answer (score 0):

Most motherboards will drop to single channel if the channels have unequal memory sizes. While this is a significant effect on synthetic benchmarks, it's a very minimal effect in the real world. In any event, the benefits of having more RAM (such as additional caching) will drastically exceed the penalty of losing dual-channel when looking at overall system performance.

Comment: I saw several comaparisions in youtube between single and dual channel for gaming. There's more than 10% difference in the fps